# WARNING : NPT_CHECK failed

Tags: ios, xcode, upnp

while building an upnp based project on xcode, it is compiling and building successfully and the app is working fine but in logs it is generating warning : NPT_CHECK failed over and over.
So my question is : what exactly NPT_CHECK is and also what exactly NPT_ERROR_CANCELLED is ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that NPT_CHECK is in fact a function defined in platinum framework source code which is being used for upnp connections and if the output is coming like this because of conditions mentioned in functions are not met.  If you are facing same problems then just trace the error to its definition.